# How do I import code in Pascal?

Tags: import, include, load, pascal

What's the Pascal way to do C's `#include "code.h"`, Python's `import code`, etc.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pascal uses

```
uses
```

to import other modules.

Comment: Thanks. Where does the `uses` command go? And do you need to explicitly provide access to the functions in the code to be imported, or by default are they all accessible?

Comment: It usually goes right after `interface` or `implementation`, but it can depend on which Pascal compiler you are using. You shouldn't have to explicitly name functions to use.

Comment: I think it also depends on which type of module we are talking about. For instance, Borland Pascal (as well as its 'spin-offs', like Delphi or Lazarus) distinguishes between *units* and *programs*. Interface and implementation are parts of a *unit*, and the `uses` keyword should indeed follow `interface` or `implementation`. A *program* module, on the other hand, doesn't include any `interface` or `implementation` sections, so `uses` either follows the program header (`program ...;`) or, in the latter's absence, opens the program module.

Answer (score 2):

While you can explicitly {$INCLUDE a file it's rarely done other than for configuration files containing compiler switches.  The only time I've ever done it was long ago when I wanted two versions of the code identical except one used coprocessor-only datatypes and the other didn't.  (And how many people these days even know that single and double types used to require either an expensive additional chip or a slow emulator?)

If you include the same code in two places you will get two copies of it in your .EXE.  If you include the same type definition in two places you'll get two types with the same name and since Pascal uses strict typing they will not match.

The normal mechanic is as Greg Hewgill says, to use the file you want.  Anything that appears in the interface of the file you use is visible, anything that's only in the implementation is not visible.  This is an all-or-nothing process, you don't specify what you are bringing in.  Think of the C# using command.

Unlike the C# version it's absolutely mandatory.  You can't use fully qualified names to get around it.